# React: Caret icon keeps moving outside of dropdown menu whenever page is resized to iPad or smaller

Tags: css, reactjs, css-position, responsive, styled-components

I have a styled react component that features a hand rolled dropdown menu including a caret icon and every time I test the responsiveness of the dropdown the caret icon pops outside. I've wrapped the dropdown  inside of a larger component to place everything on the same line and then included the icon inside of the styled select component. I've used this methodology in another app and the dropdown is completely responsive and doesn't have any issues with icon placement so I'm completely scratching my head with this one. Any help/suggestions would be great

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { FaCaretDown } from 'react-icons/fa'
import Table from '../core/Table'
import SubHeader from '../elements/SubHeader'
import EligibleOffer from './EligibleOffer'
import { tableDataProps, tableColumnProps } from '../../propTypes'

const BUNDLE_KEY = 'bundle'
const rowKey = 'id'

class OfferBundlesTable extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    bundles: PropTypes.arrayOf(tableDataProps),
    columns: tableColumnProps,
    viewedOfferIds: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
    onBundleSelect: PropTypes.func
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    viewedOfferIds: []
  }

  renderCell = (cell = {}) => (
    <div>
      {cell.title && <SubHeader>{cell.title}</SubHeader>}
      <p>{cell.details}</p>
    </div>
  )

  renderBundle = bundle => (
    <StyledOffer
      offer={bundle}
      onOfferSelect={this.props.onBundleSelect}
      viewed={this.props.viewedOfferIds.includes(bundle.OfferId)}
    />
  )

  getColumns = columns =>
    Object.entries(columns).reduce(
      (cols, [key, value]) => ({
        ...cols,
        [key]: {
          ...value,
          renderCell: key === BUNDLE_KEY ? this.renderBundle : this.renderCell
        }
      }),
      {}
    )

  render() {
    const { bundles = [], columns = [] } = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <DropdownRow>
          <StyledSelect>
            <StyledStrong>SORT BY: </StyledStrong>
            <select>
              <option>Default</option>
              <option>Promo Price (High to Low)</option>
              <option>Promo Price (Low to High)</option>
              <option>Alphabetically (A-Z)</option>
              <option>Alphabetically (Z-A)</option>
              <option>Internet Tier (High to Low)</option>
              <option>Internet Tier (Low to High)</option>
            </select>
            <StyledSelectIcon size="1.5rem" />
          </StyledSelect>
          <StyledSelect>
            <StyledStrong>CONTRACT TERMS (MONTHS):</StyledStrong>
            <select>
              <option>36</option>
              <option>24</option>
              <option>12</option>
            </select>
            <StyledSelectIcon size="1.5rem" />
          </StyledSelect>
        </DropdownRow>
        <StyledTable
          rowKey={rowKey}
          rows={bundles}
          columns={this.getColumns(columns)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const StyledTable = styled(Table)`
  th:first-child {
    width: 25%;
  }
`

const StyledOffer = styled(EligibleOffer)`
  margin-bottom: 15px;
`

const DropdownRow = styled.div`
    th:first-child {
    width: 25%;
  } 

  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  padding: 20px 30px 20px 10px;
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 42%;
`

const StyledSelectIcon = styled(FaCaretDown)`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  color: black;
  pointer-events: none;
`

const StyledSelect = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;


  select {
    padding: 5px 45px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 36px;
    appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
`

const StyledStrong = styled.strong`
  padding-right: 5px;
`

export default OfferBundlesTable
```

Comment: Can you create a working example, via [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) or something?

Comment: Yeup just added a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t35k77 and the you'll have to make the window full size in order for the caret to render inside the dropdown

Comment: I think you may need to hit 'save'.... I get this error ```Error in /~/index.js (34:43)
OfferBundlesTable is not defined```

Comment: Just saved it, should work now

Comment: Start with adding `width: 100%;` to the bit defining the `select` properties. There's nothing setting it's width, and the caret is positioned based on the div that wraps the select.

Comment: Just tried that and it seems to just move the whole icon up to the top of the dropdown, and still moves outside of the dropdown when resizing

Comment: See my answer below for a cleaner solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at your code, I would suggest an alternative approach, including the caret in the css for your select. This makes it impossible for it to move away from the select, as it's now part of it. Run the snippet below to see it work--of course you would want to put that stuff into the styled-component css definition, and remove the `<StyledSelectIcon/>` altogether [(here's a forked stackblitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-edgmwr?file=Offers.js).

**Styled component definition:**

```
const StyledSelect = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;

  select {
    padding: 5px 45px 5px 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: black;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    appearance: none;
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill="black" viewBox="0 0 320 512" height="1.5rem" width="1.5rem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M31.3 192h257.3c17.8 0 26.7 21.5 14.1 34.1L174.1 354.8c-7.8 7.8-20.5 7.8-28.3 0L17.2 226.1C4.6 213.5 13.5 192 31.3 192z"></path></svg>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 8px center;
  }
`
```

**Snippet to run here:**

```css
.customselect{
  padding: 5px 45px 5px 10px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  appearance: none;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg fill="black" viewBox="0 0 320 512" height="1.5rem" width="1.5rem" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M31.3 192h257.3c17.8 0 26.7 21.5 14.1 34.1L174.1 354.8c-7.8 7.8-20.5 7.8-28.3 0L17.2 226.1C4.6 213.5 13.5 192 31.3 192z"></path></svg>');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 8px center;
}
```

```html
<select class="customselect">
  <option>Option A</option>
  <option>Option B</option>
  <option>Option C</option>
  <option>Option D</option>
</select>
```